# Spark CSV - No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have an issue in using lambda functions on filters and maps of typed datasets in java spark applications.

I am getting this runtime error

```
ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 130, Column 126: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"; candidates are: "public static java.sql.Date org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils.toJavaDate(int)"
```

I am using the below class and spark 2.2.0. 
Full example with sample data is available in https://gitlab.com/opencell/test-bigdata

```
Dataset<CDR> cdr = spark
            .read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("delimiter", ";")
            .csv("CDR_SAMPLE.csv")
            .as(Encoders.bean(CDR.class));

    long v = cdr.filter(x -> (x.timestamp != null && x.getAccess().length()>0)).count();

    System.out.println("validated entries :" + v);
```

CDR file definition is [gitlab link](https://gitlab.com/opencell/test-bigdata/blob/master/src/main/java/org/opencell/spark/model/CDR.java)

**EDIT**

```
val cdrCSVSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType),
  StructField("quantity", DataTypes.DoubleType),
  StructField("access", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param1", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param2", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param3", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param4", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param5", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param6", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param7", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param8", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("param9", DataTypes.StringType),
  StructField("dateParam1", DataTypes.TimestampType),
  StructField("dateParam2", DataTypes.TimestampType),
  StructField("dateParam3", DataTypes.TimestampType),
  StructField("dateParam4", DataTypes.TimestampType),
  StructField("dateParam5", DataTypes.TimestampType),
  StructField("decimalParam1", DataTypes.DoubleType),
  StructField("decimalParam2", DataTypes.DoubleType),
  StructField("decimalParam3", DataTypes.DoubleType),
  StructField("decimalParam4", DataTypes.DoubleType),
  StructField("decimalParam5", DataTypes.DoubleType),
  StructField("extraParam", DataTypes.StringType)))
```

and I used this command to load the CSV document

```
val cdr = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ";").schema(cdrCSVSchema).csv("CDR_SAMPLE.csv")
```

and then tried this command to encode and run lambda function, but I am still getting error

```
cdr.as[CDR].filter(c => c.timestamp != null).show
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Define the schema explicitly since the input dataset does not have values to infer types from (for `java.sql.Date` fields).

For your case, using untyped Dataset API could be a solution (perhaps a workaround and honestly I'd recommend it to avoid unnecessary deserialization from internal row format):

```
cdr.filter(!$"timestamp".isNull).filter(length($"access") > 0).count
```

(It's Scala and I'm leaving translating it to Java as a home exercise).

The issue is that you use `inferSchema` option with most fields unavailable in the input `CDR_SAMPLE.csv` file that makes most fields of type String (which is the default type when no values are available to infer more specific type).

That makes the fields of type `java.sql.Date`, i.e. `dateParam1` up to `dateParam5`, of type String.

```
import org.opencell.spark.model.CDR
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
implicit val cdrEnc = Encoders.bean(classOf[CDR])
val cdrs = spark.read.
  option("inferSchema", "true").
  option("delimiter", ";").
  option("header", true).
  csv("/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/test-bigdata/CDR_SAMPLE.csv")
scala> cdrs.printSchema
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- access: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- param9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- decimalParam1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- decimalParam2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- decimalParam3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- decimalParam4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- decimalParam5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- extraParam: string (nullable = true)
```

Note that the fields of interest, i.e. `dateParam1` to `dateParam5`, are all strings.

```
 |-- dateParam1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateParam5: string (nullable = true)
```

The issue surfaces when you "pretend" the type of the fields is different by using the encoder as defined in `CDR` class which says:

```
private Date dateParam1;
private Date dateParam2;
private Date dateParam3; 
private Date dateParam4; 
private Date dateParam5;
```

That's the root cause of the issue. There is a difference between what Spark could infer from the class. Without the conversion the code would've worked, but since you insisted...

```
cdrs.as[CDR]. // <-- HERE is the issue = types don't match
  filter(cdr => cdr.timestamp != null).
  show // <-- trigger conversion
```

It does not really matter what field you access in `filter` operator. The issue is that the conversion takes place that leads to incorrect execution (and whole-stage Java code generation).

I doubt Spark can do much about it since you requested `inferSchema` with a dataset with no values to use for the type inference. The best bet is to define the schema explicitly and use `schema(...)` operator to set it.